# Make manual slideshow automatic

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to make a manual slideshow automatic

here is the code i have so far

```
<script>

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);


function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.display = "none";
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(showDivs, 6000);
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section-split one-third" id="copy-here">
<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Elsham News</h3>
<div>
<button class="arrows" id="arrow-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</button>
<button class="arrows" id="arrow-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</button>
</div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
   2
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
   3
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
   4
  </div>

  </div>
```

I want to make the slider automatic as well as retaining the controls to switch between slides manually

I have tried to setTimeOut but with no luck

Comment: You HTML code is not valid: it lacks a closing `div`. And your `setTimeout` calls a `function` that does not exist.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ corrected now, was copy and pasted from dev tools in a rush

Answer (score 0):

To make it automated you have to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. You can just call the `plusDivs` function on certain interval to make it slide automatically.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);


function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) { 
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1;}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.display = "none";
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
setInterval(plusDivs.bind(null, 1), 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section-split one-third" id="copy-here">
<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Elsham News</h3>
<div>
<button class="arrows" id="arrow-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</button>
<button class="arrows" id="arrow-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</button>
</div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
   2
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
   3
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
   4
  </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```